# Angular ng-style with more than 2 conditional outputs

Tags: angularjs, ng-style

My text stye is dependent on 3 conditions:

condition1: color should be green

condition2: color should be blue

condition3: color should be red

Thus, there are 3 outputs for the same style (color).

I could come up with the following expression:

```
<p ng-style="condition1  ? { color:'green' } : { color: 'blue' }">
```

Is there a way to change the above code such that it can accommodate all the 3 conditions and outputs ?

**EDIT**: There are workarounds to achieve this using controller; but I was wondering whether this can be done in the html itself

Comment: How about a function in controller to count that for you?

Comment: Yes, there are workarounds to achieve this using controller; but I was wondering whether this can be done only in the html..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Only apply color if any of the condition is true and use `?:` operator to check for other conditions in false value. Do not apply style if none of the conditions are true.

```js
var app = angular.module("MyApp", []).controller("MyCtrl", function ($scope) {
    $scope.cond1 = false;
    $scope.cond2 = false;
    $scope.cond3 = true;
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<body ng-app="MyApp">
  <div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
     <p ng-style="cond1  ? { color:'green' } : cond2 ? {color: 'blue'} : cond3 ? {color: 'red'} : {color: ''}">Hello World!</p>
  </div>

</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

you can simply do it like this :

```
<p ng-style="condition1  ? { color:'green' } : condition2 ? { color:'blue' } : { color:'red' }">
```